# iOS 7 jQuery animation fail on mobile opera

Tags: jquery, mobile, ios7, safari, jquery-animate

I'm working on drupal theme which should support iOS7 device. On my page I placed little button that scrolls to exact page position (After specified item). I wrote simple function:

```
$('#scrollbutton').click(function(e){
            e = e || event;
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            //offset.left -= 20;
            offset.top += 1;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: offset.top,
                scrollLeft: offset.left
            });
}
```

Works fine on every device (mobile or not) but iOS7 (OS 7_0_4 like mac OS X Safari/9537.53). On iOS7 screen flashes and then jumps to the top of the page.
I find out that some versions of mobile safari have bug in offset function. So I tried to fix it using this advice https://gist.github.com/Craga89/661844#comments also check if iOS version is higher or equal 7.0 and lower than 8. It's not working for me.

I will be greatefull for every advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what is wrong. I still don't know why, but jQuery animate function fails. Best thing is that after remove scrollLeft: offset.left it works perfectly.